# Delete last(recent) image from gallery from internal memory

Tags: android

I want to delete image from gallery that was most recently captured. I have followed a couple of SO questions, but nothing seems to work. Can anyone give me a simple code that works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample code:

```
public void deleteImage() {

    File f = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures");

    File [] files = f.listFiles();

    Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(File a, File b) {
            if (a.lastModified() < b.lastModified())
                return 1;
            if (a.lastModified() > b.lastModified())
                return -1;
            return 0;
        }
    });

    files[0].delete();
}
```

This code sorts the files in gallery folder by time of last modification, and delete the most recent file.

Comment: can you give me an example of path to gallery here?

Comment: From a device running Android Oreo: `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera`

Comment: Are you sure that your code is correct in syntax terms? Its giving me errors like unexpected tokens, invalid declaration, etc. Also, how am I supposed to use your code like should I put this entire code in a function and call the function or some other way?

Comment: There may be a few misplaced tokens, as I typed it here from memory. It is a sample piece, and can be used as a function seperately or in any block of code as needed. It is standalone.

Comment: you have no idea of how much help you have given me! Thanks a ton bro, you really rock :D